# Django Rest Framework - customize default list view to show unique values for ManyToMany fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My models are bound with multiple fields using ManyToMany and "through" property something like this:

```
class KLA():
    version = ForeignKey("Version", on_delete=CASCADE)
    stages = ManyToManyField('Stage',through='KlasOutcomes', blank=True)
    objectives = ManyToManyField('Objective', through='KlasOutcomes', blank=True)
    outcomes = ManyToManyField('Outcome', through='KlasOutcomes', blank=True)

class KlaSerializer(SerializerCacheMixin, ModelSerializer):
    version = VersionSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = KLA
        list_serializer_class = CachedListSerializer
        fields = ('outcomes', 'version', 'stages')
```

I am trying to return unique values for a specific field that is otherwise repeated due to combination of other fields in the table like this:
[image]

In other word, "stages" should have only one entry 23 in the list.

I tried using following to return unique stages for my model:

```
@property
def stages(self):
    return self.stage_set.all()
```

But it doesn't help, gives following error:
[image]

Comment: Are you remove unique value ??. then, 
```stages = ManyToManyField('Stage',through='KlasOutcomes', blank=True,unique=True)```

Comment: getting `KLA.stages: (fields.E330) ManyToManyFields cannot be unique.` with `unique=True`

Comment: Please remove already data from table and then insert.This error will show if having same value

Comment: Complete row in the table is unique, but I do not want to see duplicates values in JSON/api list result. This api will be consumed by client in JSON format too.
data can not be cleared as this is from production.